# C# Properties, is this a bad practice?

Tags: c#, properties

I'm new to C# and OOP in general. I've just learned about Properties in c# -which have a get and set method.

Is it bad practice to update one property from within the Set of another property like in the code example below?

```
    private int _prop1;

    public int Prop1
    {
        get { return _prop1; }
        set { _prop1 = value; OnPropertyChanged("Prop1"); Prop2 = value; }
    }

    private int _prop2;

    public int Prop2
    {
        get { return _prop2; }
        set { _prop2 = value; }
    }
```

Comment: Not necessarily. Changing one property from another might be exactly what you need.

Comment: There is no genereal "yes" or "no" to this question. There may be reasons to cause such side-effects, you should however document them in some way.

Comment: What i might add, is you are doing it the right way, because instead of changing the _prop2, you are calling the setter method of the Prop2, and you are still applying OOP concepts, and not breaking encapsulation

Comment: I'd also add that since `Prop2` doesn't modify it's data at all, it'd be safe(r) to have it be an auto property `public int Prop2 { get; set; }` vs exposing the backing property (which some people might inappropriately directly modify vs using the property).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it is bad practice if both properties are read-write, because of the confusion it could create. It is OK though if the affected property is readonly. Here is an OK example:

```
public int LivesRemaining {get; set;}

public bool IsDead {get => LivesRemaining == 0}
```

Setting `LivesRemaining = 0` will cause the `IsDead` property to become `true`. But this is hardly surprising or confusing.